# IBM Cloud: How to find details on deleted, but not reclaimed resource located in a deleted resource group?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have deleted a service instance in my IBM Cloud account. I can see that it is listed for scheduled reclamation:

```
$ ibmcloud resource reclamations
List all resource reclamations under account someID as Henrik...
OK

ID                                     Resource Instance ID                   Entity CRN                                                                                                            State            Target Time   
eb51adc4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b83ec1fb2f8f   b4c05160-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-fa42e60d7778   crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloudcerts:us-south:a/someID:b4c05160-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-fa42e60d7778::   SCHEDULED        2021-09-28T06:31:01Z
```

When I try to look up details on the resource instance using the given ID, it cannot find it. Why? How can I see details?

```
$ ibmcloud resource service-instance b4c05160-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-fa42e60d7778
Retrieving service instance b4c05160-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-fa42e60d7778 in resource group default under account Henrik's Account as Henrik...
FAILED
Service instance b4c05160-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-fa42e60d7778 was not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the resource group is still available, adding it to "[ibmcloud resource service-instance](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_commands_resource#ibmcloud_resource_service_instance)" as parameter should help find the resource and fetch its details.

If the resource group has been deleted, then the [resource controller API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller/resource-controller#get-resource-instance) needs to be used. Use something like the following with TOKEN being an IAM access token.

```
curl -s -X GET https://resource-controller.cloud.ibm.com/v2/resource_instances/b4c05160-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-fa42e60d7778 -H "Authorization: $TOKEN"
```